# query calculation between records

Tags: sql, ms-access, record

This is a simplified representation :

Suppose I have this query :

```
SELECT DISTINCT T.Description, T.ParamName, T.SetValue, T.ParamID
```

which returns this result :

| Description | ParamName | SetValue | ParamID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PA | Amount1 | 6 | 312 |
| PA | Amount2 | 6 | 314 |
| PA | Amount3 | 160 | 180 |
| PB | Amount2 | 6 | 312 |
| PB | Amount1 | 12 | 314 |
| PB | Amount3 | 245 | 180 |

Is there a way to query for each Description example Pa= (Amount1+Amount2)*Amount3
In access i would like to have

| Descriptio | Amount1 | Amount2 | Amout3 | (Amount1+Amount2)*Amount3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PA | PA-Amount1 | PA-Amount2 | PA-Amount3 | (PA-Amount1+PA-Amount2)*PA-Amount3 |
| PB | PB-Amount1 | PB-Amount2 | PA-Amount3 | (PB-Amount1+PB-Amount2)*PB-Amount3 |

Comment: Edit your question and show. the results you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you want using conditional aggregation:

```
select pa,
       (max(iif(paramname = 'Amount1', setvalue, 0)) +
        max(iif(paramname = 'Amount2', setvalue, 0))
       ) *
        max(iif(paramname = 'Amount3', setvalue, 0)) 
from t
group by pa;
```